# Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*')              
     ->from('books');   
$this->db->where('price', $filter['price']); 
/* $filter is an array, suppose value is 
$filter = array(99,199,299)
*/  
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

getting the following error

> ----------------------------------------------- Error Number: 1054  Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'  SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `price` = `Array` ------------------------------------------------

Comment: You are looking for [`where_in()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Answer (score 1):

Dont you want to generate a `WHERE price IN (1,2,3)` type sql syntax, as you have an array of prices and not just a single price.

If so look at this example

```
$filter = array(99,199,299);

$this->db->select('*')              
     ->from('books');   

$this->db->where_in('price', $filter); 
// Produces: WHERE price IN (99,199,299)
```

Comment: @devpro Thanks for spotting the typo

Answer (score 1):

Use where_in

```
$this->db->select('*') ;    
$this->db->from('books'); # Changed $this->db->where_in('price', $filter); # Changed, pass array to this     
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Your array doesn't have any index pointer call price(filter = array(99,199,299))

So you have to pass array to where_inclause like this where_in('price', filter)

Comment: Good explanation brother once again

Comment: Ohh what the bug is it I am adding my answer and decided to ignore and than just edit your answer adding one semi colon and what happened it changed the answer. Using android app... Abdullah I m realy sorry how can I change it? Ohh man what a bug in app

Comment: Finally I recover it ohh I really apologize for this  :(